Where is he working?
Inspired by @Will Octagon Gibson Beginner Puzzles, here is my attempt.
My friend said, "My manager asked me to do an inventory at this Specialty Shop I am working at right now. I counted 160 bags, 90 Urns, 270 pots and 190 balls."
What specialty shop was it?

It was a

 Special(ty) TEA SHOP. Because you can have 106(ty) tea (160) bags, 9(ty) tea (90) urns, 207(ty) tea (270) pots and 109(ty) tea (190) balls.


It helped the fact that I am British.

urns and balls? dafuq? :-)
